# "Solved" Bootstrap 5.3.2 gap between the nav and screen on left and right both on full screen and when the screen size is reduced

Tags: css, responsive

The issue I am having is that when I use Bootstrap the latest release and I use div class container-fluid so I can use the grid system my navbar does not display the full length of the screen it stops on both sides short when the screen is full size and when it is reduced to the browsers smallest size and all sizes in between. When I remove the div class container-fluid  the navbar displays the full length as expected. Can someone please explain what the issue is here and why that happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Find</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is the my site">
    <meta name="keywords" content="bootstrap, css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-name">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expandme">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="expandme">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="../index.html" class="nav=item nav-link">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="about.html" class="nav=item nav-link">About Us</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="gallery.html" class="nav=item nav-link">Gallery</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="contact.html" class="nav=item nav-link">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The examples in the documentation do it the exact other way around - they have `.container-fluid` wrapped into `.navbar`.

Comment: Okay, "Solved"... What's the solution? You should post it for others to learn.